# complex analysis radius convergence confusing

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Problem: Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n z^n, a\in \mathbb C$

My work: $$R = \frac{1}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sup \sqrt[n]{|a^n|}}=\frac{1}{|a|}$$

Hence $R=\frac{1}{|a|}~~ if~~ a>0$,  $R= \infty~~ if~~ a=0$

My question: What is different if $a \in \mathbb Z$ and $a\neq 0$

Please, explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

None. $\mathbb Z$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: In that case, we have an argument for a <0 while there is  not when a in C, right? since |a| in C is always positive (norm of a) , but if a in Z, a can be negative and 1/|a| = -1/a if a <0. Am I right?

Comment: $|a|$  is never negative. If $a<0$, then $-a=|a|>0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in \mathbb Z$ and $a\neq0$, then $|a|\in \mathbb N$. So, as upper answer said nothing will change, because it is just a subset of $\mathbb R.$